# MySQL INNER JOIN fails to return correct data in a large table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to compare the records of two tables in a database. One table (Clients) contains almost 40,000 records and the other table (Users) contains about 1,500 records. Here is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT
   Clients.Name
 , Clients.IDCardNo
 , Users.IDCardNo
FROM
  Clients INNER JOIN Users
ON
  (Clients.IDCardNo = REPLACE(Users.IDCardNo, '-', ''));
```

(A client's ID card number in Users database has redundant hyphens that I have to remove before comparing because in Clients database, no ID card number has hyphen. That is why I am using REPLACE() in MySQL)

To my surprise, MySQL returns almost 180,000 records (I do not have that many records in all of my databases combined!) where each record has the same Clients.Name and Clients.IDCardNo!

Is this a bug in MySQL because it can't scale and handle large data or is there something wrong with my SQL statement?

Comment: No it is not a bug in MySQL. People use joins all the time and it works. Limit your query to one `IDCardNo` and see what you get. Most likely one `IDCardNo` matches many records in Users table.

Comment: @CodingYoshi  It works well for small tables. I split my large database into a smaller database with only 2000 records at it worked! No, one `IDCardNo` cannot match many records in Users table because it is checked to be unique before a user can register.

Comment: Unrelated: Consider to have both ID card numbers to have the same format. Either with or without the hyphen. That way indexes on both can be used for the query.

Comment: Clients.IDCardNo is an int data type and Users.IDCardNo is varchar?

Comment: @stickybit  I tried that. I even created a copy of my Users table and removed all hyphens in there. It seems like that for some weird reason, MySQL considers records with different ID card numbers as the same!

Comment: Perhaps its doing a float data type comparision.

Comment: @P.Salmon  No, both are varchar variables. They have different lengths though. Could you please explain what a float data type comparison is? I executed the first command in Gordon's answer and it returned 93 records that claimed to be the same, but they were totally different records!

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html

Comment: @P.Salmon  That makes sense. I haven't done any data type casting though. How can I prevent MySQL from doing this on its own?

Comment: Note that for case insensitive collations (*_ci) `abc`, `Abc` and `ABC` are all considered to be equal.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thanks. The data stored in ID Card numbers in Clients consist of digits only. MySQL is considering records like 00195421 and 00195669 the same!

Comment: @stressedout I don't think MySQL will treat 00195421 and 00195669 as the same. You probably missunderstood Gordon's query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a "bug" in the database.  This is how `JOIN` works.  You have duplicates in your data, which is causing multiple results in the `JOIN`.

You can check this out with these queries:

```
select c.IDCardNo
from clients c
group by c.IDCardNo
having count(*) > 1;
```

and:

```
select REPLACE(u.IDCardNo, '-', ''))
from users u
group by REPLACE(u.IDCardNo, '-', ''))
having count(*) > 1;
```

If there is a "bug", it is in the data or your assumption that these `IDCardNo` is unique.

Comment: Hmm. It's weird. Something really weird happened! I executed your first command and it returned 93 records. But all of them are different records. I mean they are clearly different ID card numbers! But MySQL considers them the same! How's that possible?!!

Comment: @stressedout the returned 93 values are not equal. These are values which have duplicates in the table. Replace the SELECT clause with `select c.IDCardNo, count(*)` to see the number of duplicates per value.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel  Thanks. Now I understand better, I think. It says that there are 1555 records with blank ID Card numbers. That's probably what is causing this issue. I still do not understand something. If, let's say, Alex and Bob have duplicate ID Card Numbers, MySQL returns Alex twice when I run that command. Is that normal?

Comment: @stressedout "Is that normal?" - Yes. As Gordon wrote -  "This is how JOIN works."

Comment: @PaulSpiegel  I wasn't using JOIN this time, just a simple SELECT statement, but I get your point that my question was naive. :P Anyway, how can I modify my SQL query to SELECT duplicate records only once?

Comment: @stressedout . . . Ask another question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are looking for.